# Removing whitespace from the bottom of footer?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've looked into a few other answers to this question online and tried a few things like fixed, sticky and absolute positioning and editing the margin-bottom, but I still keep having a problem of excess whitespace at the bottom! The 'nav' represents the footer:

```
.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.events {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fbba5c;
  margin-top: auto;
  left: 0;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Ubuntu, Oxygen, -apple-system,
    "Segoe UI", Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: -20px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any ideas what might be causing it? Any insight would be very welcome!

Comment: Hi can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: But with a quick glance, maybe try adding `bottom: 0;` as well as `position: absolute;` to `.nav` in CSS

Answer (score 1):

It's because the nav footer is absolutely positioned and the content between the footer and the top of the document is small.
Try setting the min-height of the middle div to 100vh or 120vh and make the footer relatively positioned.
Just a wild guess, since you didn't provide the HTML or a reproduction link on Codepen/jsFiddle. Also, try `bottom: 0;` if `position: absolute` is a must.